# How does AC move past equilibrium?

Tags: electricity

From what I understand, the net movement should be zero since AC is periodic and the charges should not move anywhere.

Are they picked up by a receiver or something when they are pushed just far enough??

Comment: The charges don't move a lot. They move in each direction for 1/120 of a second, so net motion is not much. Drift speed is about .25 millimeter per second, do divide that by 120 to get distance traveled.

Comment: The electrons in an A/C circuit rapidly "wiggle" about a fixed position.